# formik with typescript set initalvalue in withFormik HOC

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik, react-typescript

I am adding formik with typescript and react to my project, so i am using withFormik hook as an HOC, the issue i am facing is that i am not able to set initialvalue (defined in hoc) to the response i am getting from the api

login.tsx

```
import { FormikProps } from "formik";
export interface FormValues {
  title: string;
}

export const Login: React.FC<FormikProps<FormValues>> = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setTitle(json.title));
  }, []);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState<string | null>(null);


  const { handleSubmit, handleBlur, handleChange, touched, errors, values } =
    props;

  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">

      <div className={classes.paper}>


        <form className={classes.form} noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="title"
            label="Title"
            name="title"
            value={values.title}
            autoFocus
            autoComplete="off"
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
          />

         

          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.submit}
          >
            Sign In
          </Button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

login.hoc.tsx

```
import { Form, FormikProps, FormikValues, useFormik, withFormik } from "formik";


import { FormValues, Login } from "./index";
interface MyFormikProps {

}

export const LoginView = withFormik<MyFormikProps, FormValues>({
  enableReinitialize: true,
  mapPropsToValues: (props) => {
    return { title:"" };
  },

  handleSubmit: (values) => {
    console.log(values);
  },
})(Login);
```

This works perfectly fine, but my issue is that suppose i hit an api in didmount of login.tsx and then you can see i set the "title" to response what i am getting from api

Now I want to set initialValue of "title" to what i am getting as response from api

Comment: What are the exact Typescript issues you're facing? Could you please provide more details. And also: why don't you try using hooks instead of HOCs, since you're using functional components that would be more convenient

Comment: more than a typescript issue,i am facing issue in passing  a prop to this withFormik which i am unfamiliar with :)

Comment: I am not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish, but maybe you can accomplish it by implementing your custom `useFormik` hook and add your custom state values and everything else there. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-cookies-qiqyh?file=/src/Form.tsx) is an example of how can you do something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Why Your HOC Won't Work

Your current setup cannot possibly work because the hierarchy is incorrect.  The `withFormik` HOC creates the initial value from the `props` of the component.  But the API response is never in the `props` of `Login`.  It's saved to a state *inside* of the `Login` component.  An HOC, which is *outside*, cannot access it.

You could have a setup where `withFormik` gets the correct API data in `props`, but you would need to move the API fetching up to a higher level.

```
// component which renders the form, no more API fetch
export const Login: React.FC<FormikProps<FormValues>> = (props) => {/*...*/}

// data passed down from API
interface MyFormikProps {
  title: string | null;
}

// component which sets up the form
export const LoginView = withFormik<MyFormikProps, FormValues>({
  enableReinitialize: true,
  mapPropsToValues: (props) => ({
    title: props.title ?? "" // fallback if null
  }),
  handleSubmit: (values) => {
    console.log(values);
  }
})(Login);

// component which loads the data
export const ApiLoginForm = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState<string | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setTitle(json.title));
  }, []);

  return <LoginView title={title} />;
};
```

[Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-api-initial-values-3xxu3?file=/src/App.tsx)

#### Handling Async Initial Values

The value from your API will take time to resolve.  It's tricky to use it as an **initial** value because the initial value must be present as soon as the form is mounted.  What we are doing here is falling back to using an empty string `''` as an initial value.  Then once the API response loads, the form resets with the new initial value because you've used the [`enableReinitialize` setting](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#enablereinitialize-boolean).

This will reset the whole form, and could cause a bad user experience if the API response is slow. You wouldn't want to override user inputs if the user entered text in form before the response came back.  You could disable the field until the response is available.  Or you could make the modification conditional by checking if `touched.title` is `true` or if `values.title`.  If you want to get more sophisticated about how you modify the form, then read on...

#### Programmatically Modifying Formik Values

You can make use of the [`setFieldValue` prop](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#setfieldvalue-field-string-value-any-shouldvalidate-boolean--void) from `FormikProps` to imperatively modify any value of your field.  Instead of changing the initial value, you can change the current value by calling `setFieldValue`.

This approach is more in line with your current setup as it allows you to keep the API calls inside of `Login`.  We don't need the local `title` state.  Instead of calling `setTitle` with the resolved response, you can call `setFieldValue`.

```
export const Login: React.FC<FormikProps<FormValues>> = (props) => {

  // access setFieldValue from props
  const { setFieldValue, handleSubmit, handleBlur, handleChange, touched, errors, values } =
    props;

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      // could make this conditional, or add extra logic here
      .then((json) => setFieldValue("title", json.title));
  }, []);

  return (
    /* same JSX as before */
  )
};
```

[Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-api-modified-values-zuzjx?file=/src/App.tsx)